# masonry-layout in Next Js gives me ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to use the masonry-layout library by david desandro in my Next app, here is a link https://masonry.desandro.com/#install and when i do, everything works perfectly, I get the masonry layout i want, Here is how i'm using it and it works like it should.

```
import Masonry from "masonry-layout";
 var msnry = new Masonry(".grid", {
    //options
  });
 <div
        onClick={() => {
          contextValue.setOpenTextArea(false);
        }}
        className="grid"
        // data-packery='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "gutter": 10 }'
        data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item",
          "columnWidth": 300
         }'
      >
        {contextValue?.notes?.length > 0 ? (
          contextValue.notes?.map((note: any, index: any) => ()}
//rest of the code....
```

But on my terminal i get the error....I also get the exact same error with he's packery library;

```
 ⨯ node_modules\masonry-layout\masonry.js (33:1) @ eval
 ⨯ ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Documents\Next Js Projects\keep\client\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)       
    at eval (./components/showNotes/ShowNotes.tsx:15:72)
    at (ssr)/./components/showNotes/ShowNotes.tsx (C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Documents\Next Js Projects\keep\client\.next\server\app\page.js:415:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Documents\Next Js Projects\keep\client\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43) 
//And this causes my app to break
```

Here is the masonry.js file code in my node_modules file

```
/*!
 * Masonry v4.2.2
 * Cascading grid layout library
 * https://masonry.desandro.com
 * MIT License
 * by David DeSandro
 */
//This is the only part where window is mentioned,
(function (window, factory) {
  // universal module definition
  /* jshint strict: false */ /*globals define, module, require */

//Here i tried this if(typeOf !== window) {
  if (typeof define == "function" && define.amd) {
    // AMD
    define(["outlayer/outlayer", "get-size/get-size"], factory);
  } else if (typeof module == "object" && module.exports) {
    // CommonJS
//Another thing worth mentioning is that require("outlayer") here wants a type definition and i've tried installing it, i don't know if it's necessary but right now i dunno what else to try.
    module.exports = factory(require("outlayer"), require("get-size"));
  } else {
    // browser global
    window.Masonry = factory(window.Outlayer, window.getSize);
  }
}
})
//I also did the same if check for this point
(window, function factory(Outlayer, getSize) {
  "use strict";

  // -------------------------- masonryDefinition -------------------------- //

  // create an Outlayer layout class
  var Masonry = Outlayer.create("masonry");
  // isFitWidth -> fitWidth
  Masonry.compatOptions.fitWidth = "isFitWidth";

  var proto = Masonry.prototype;
//Rest of the code......
```

And this in turn cause my app to break on netlify

```
 Generating static pages (0/10) ...
4:06:38 PM:    Generating static pages (2/10)
4:06:38 PM:    Generating static pages (4/10)
4:06:38 PM:    Generating static pages (7/10)
4:06:39 PM: ReferenceError: window is not defined
4:06:39 PM:     at 51616 (/opt/build/repo/.next/server/chunks/247.js:1:36258)
4:06:39 PM:     at __webpack_require__ (/opt/build/repo/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:161)
4:06:39 PM:     at 19826 (/opt/build/repo/.next/server/app/page.js:1:56295)
4:06:39 PM:     at __webpack_require__ (/opt/build/repo/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:161)
4:06:39 PM:     at I (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:43:5587)
4:06:39 PM:     at C (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:43:4266)
4:06:39 PM:     at rp (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:27:25013)
4:06:39 PM:     at nh (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:27:48815)
4:06:39 PM:     at ny (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:27:53901)
4:06:39 PM:     at nd (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:27:45663)
4:06:39 PM: Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
4:06:39 PM: ReferenceError: window is not defined
4:06:39 PM:     at 51616 (/opt/build/repo/.next/server/chunks/247.js:1:36258)
4:06:39 PM:     at __webpack_require__ (/opt/build/repo/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:161)
4:06:39 PM:     at 19826 (/opt/build/repo/.next/server/app/page.js:1:56295)
4:06:39 PM:     at __webpack_require__ (/opt/build/repo/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:161)
4:06:39 PM:     at I (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:43:5587)
4:06:39 PM:     at C (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:43:4266)
4:06:39 PM:     at rp (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:27:25013)
4:06:39 PM:     at nh (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:27:48815)
4:06:39 PM:     at ny (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:27:53901)
4:06:39 PM:     at nd (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:27:45663)
4:06:39 PM:  ✓ Generating static pages (10/10)
4:06:39 PM: > Export encountered errors on following paths:
4:06:39 PM:     /page: /
4:06:39 PM: ​
4:06:39 PM: "build.command" failed
```

At this point i don't know what else to try or do, I need help at this point.

Answer (score 0):

When you get this error for a lib when using a [JavaScript metaframework](https://www.ombulabs.com/blog/javascript/what-is-a-javascript-meta-framework.html) like NextJS it means that the code doesn't support [prerendering](https://nextjs.org/learn-pages-router/basics/data-fetching/pre-rendering). The easiest way to fix this is to [disable SSR for that component](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading#with-no-ssr). Basically in the case of Masonry you are probably going to make a react wrapper and essentially before using that wrapper you should do something to the effect of

```js
const DynamicMason = dynamic(() => import('../components/Mason'), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

Comment: i tried this and it didn't work, not only do i keep getting the ReferenceError: window is not defined error but it's also causing a re-render and i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong to cause this. Bottomline though is i am still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially I used Dynamic import for it, so Masonry only gets imported at all if the window is not undefined
So Here's what I eventually did and it works.
The else statement and if check is there because I wanted to do a layout switch from a masonry layout to a flex layout and i needed to remove all instance of it else it would not work

```
const gridRef = useRef(null);
  const masonryRef = useRef(null);

  //Useffect to run Masonry
  useEffect(() => {
    //Checks if the window is undefined first
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      let masonryInstance: any;
      // If changeNoteLayout is false then masonry-layout should be imported and a new instance of for it
      if (contextValue?.changeNoteLayout == false) {
        import("masonry-layout").then((module) => {
          const Masonry = module.default;
          masonryInstance = new Masonry(gridRef.current, {
            // options
            // itemSelector: ".grid-item",
            // columnWidth: 160,
            // gutter: 20,
          });
          masonryRef.current = masonryInstance;
        });
      }
      return () => {
        if (masonryInstance) {
          masonryInstance.destroy();
        }
      };
    }
  });
```

And in my jsx

```
 <div ref={gridRef}></div>
```

I still think this answer can be improved too.